# Removing download Facebook App link from Facebook login page

Tags: android, facebook, api, authentication, google-play

I'm building a native Android app for a client and one of the areas of the app allows the user to post their score from a quiz to their Facebook wall. This app is on devices that are handed out to the public and not on their own person device. The problem is that the Facebook login page has a link to Google Play that says "Get Facebook for Android and browse faster". When tapping this the user is bumped out of the app to the Market. I need to keep people within the app. Giving the user the ability to enter Google Play and download the Facebook app or any other app is not going to work.

There's the added problem that the device has a protective casing that covers the hardware navigation buttons. So the user doesn't have access to the back button to return to the app.

Any ideas if how to get a modified login page?